# Cannot find Yodlee DAG fields in API

Tags: yodlee

In the Yodlee DAG templates, there are fields for ISIN and SEDOL and some other fields that we do not see in the API.  Are these fields able to be pulled via the Yodlee API?

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded the complete Yodlee SDK folder contents and search the Javadoc/index-all.html for sedol and ISIN you will find multiple properties with these names all in Investment/SEcurities related structures/classes.

A warning, just because the property is there does not mean it's populated. Just because it's populated doesn't mean it's populated with all information (e.g often times sensitive information is obsecured to the last 4 digits such as Account #s).

The fact that I see it as a property in the SecuritiesSearchCriteria however might lend hope to the fact that it is populated with usable info.

Answer (score 0):

ISIN is an unique identifier of a holding in India and SEDOL is a unique identifier used in UK and Ireland. Hence they will be populated for investment account of users from those parts. Also their population is dependent on the availability at the end site(The website from where we are scraping the data)

You can get these details through Yodlee's DataService API.
This API will return the itemSummary which contains ItemData object.
This ItemData object contains the list of accounts and then each account will have Investment data and this investment data contains Holding details which contains all the details for a holding. In the Holding details you can find the method to retrieve ISIN , SEDOL etc.